# Unexpected wildcard behavior in find (command shell)

Tags: windows, cmd

My question is related to the Windows command shell, and I know that PowerShell and other shells available can do it but I want to learn the nuance here.

I've been digging around lately and reading documentation on "find". Specifically, the following is noted on TechNet:

**Using wildcards**

*You cannot use wildcards (* and ?) in file names or extensions that you specify with the find command. To search for a string in a set of files that you specify with wildcards, you can use the find command within a for command.*

So, I tried the following:

```
C:\Users\Public>echo some random apple text here > a.txt

C:\Users\Public>echo some more random text here > aa.txt

C:\Users\Public>echo some more random blah blah here > aaa.txt

C:\Users\Public>echo some more random crap here > aaa

C:\Users\Public>echo some more random apple here > aaa
```

Then I tried some different versions of find:

```
C:\Users\Public>find "apple" C:\
Access denied - C:\

C:\Users\Public>find "apple" C:\Users
Access denied - C:\USERS

C:\Users\Public>find "apple" C:\Users\Public
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC

C:\Users\Public>find "apple" C:\Users\Public\
File not found - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\

C:\Users\Public>find "apple" C:\Users\Public\*

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\A.TXT
some random apple text here

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\AA.TXT

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\AAA
some more random apple here

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\AAA.TXT
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DESKTOP

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DESKTOP.INI
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOWNLOADS
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\FAVORITES
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\LIBRARIES
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\MUSIC
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\PICTURES
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\RECORDED TV
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\VIDEOS

C:\Users\Public>find "apple" C:\Users\Public\*.*

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\A.TXT
some random apple text here

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\AA.TXT

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\AAA
some more random apple here

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\AAA.TXT
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DESKTOP

---------- C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DESKTOP.INI
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOWNLOADS
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\FAVORITES
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\LIBRARIES
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\MUSIC
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\PICTURES
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\RECORDED TV
Access denied - C:\USERS\PUBLIC\VIDEOS

C:\Users\Public>
```

So, my conclusions:

- some form of wildcarding is need.
- it does't seem to matter if it's * or *.*
- *.* does not just look for filename.ext, it matches anything (e.g., aaa)

What am I missing? Why does the documentation say that it's not supported (refs below)?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655(v=ws.11).aspx (remarks, bullet 4)

Comment: Old documentation...

Comment: Wildcards in `cmd` act different from "good old DOS". `*` means "any file", `*.*` means "any file with any extension" (even empty extension). To get files without extension, you can use `*.`

Comment: ... and of course folders are not files, so the "access denied"

Comment: Whenever support for wildcards was added (a long time ago) someone neglected to update the documentation.  There's a lot of that.  Even so, you're probably better off using findstr.

Comment: Side note:  If you run into a situation where wildcards *actually* don't work, you can use the `FOR` loop to compensate.  For example, if wildcards didn't work with the `FIND` command, you could use `FOR %F IN ("C:\Users\Public\*") DO FIND "apple" "%F"`.  Double the `%` if the command is being written into a batch file ( `FOR %%F IN ("C:\Users\Public\*") DO FIND "apple" "%%F"` )

Comment: Wildcard expansion is generally done by the filesystem itself in the `NtQueryDirectoryFile` system call, which may use [`FsRtlIsNameInExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546850) to filter the directory listing. WinAPI `FindFirstFile` first has to translate the pattern to NT form. A "?" anywhere becomes `DOS_QM` (i.e. `>`). A "." followed by "?" or "\*" is changed to `DOS_DOT` (i.e. `"`). A "\*" followed by "." becomes `DOS_STAR` (i.e. `<`), but the "." is removed if it's at the end, and exactly "\*.\*" becomes "\*".

Comment: That said, find.exe appears to strip a trailing "." from the passed file pattern, so it can't search for just files without an extension because `FindFirstFile` needs "\*." to query the filesystem with `DOS_STAR`. For example, "A*." should only match "AAA", not "AAA.TXT". Moreover, unlike a lot of programs, you can't even manually pass in the NT wildcard spec `"A<"` because it does its own filename matching on top of what the filesystem does, and it doesn't grok NT `DOS_STAR`, `DOS_QM`, and `DOS_DOT`.

Comment: @Stephan, this has nothing to do with wildcards in CMD. It's not a Unix shell that expands wildcards on the command line before running a program. Wildcard expansion is the responsibility of each program, but only if it wants to do something special. Otherwise it can just pass the file pattern to `FindFirstFile` and use whatever the filesystem returns.